# ¿como hacer para que se ejecute una animacion segun la orientacion del movil o la tablet?

Tags: javascript

Este codigo es para que se ejecuten unas animaciones siempre y cuando el ancho del navegador o viewport esté entre los 480 y 800 pixeles:

```
if ( window.innerWidth > 480 && window.innerWidth < 800 ) {
  //aqui vienen 200 lineas de codigo de animaciones
}
```

Hasta ahí todo bien. El problema es que si un usuario entra con un movil de 450 de ancho y 600 de alto, y lo gira 90 grados, su ancho cambia a 600, pero mis animaciones no funcionarían aunque estarían dentro del rango de mi condicional, porque inicialmente el usuario entro con un ancho de 450 (que esta debajo de los 480), y cuando giró no actualizó la pagina, por lo que no se ejecutarían los `scripts` a menos que él actualice la web (lo que es poco probable). Esto me daría errores. Las animaciones no funcionarían si los usuarios giraran con sus moviles o tablets.

Entonces lo que se me ocurre es hacer un condicional que especifique que, cuando esté entre 480 y 800 en PORTRAIT (vertical) Y ADEMAS cuando esté entre 480 y 800 en LANDSCAPTE (horizontal) me aplique las animaciones.

Pero nunca he usado la propiedad ORIENTATION de `javascript`, y como mi web aun esta en local (en una laptop) no tengo como probar que funcione correctamente la orientacion, por eso necesito que me hagan el favor de revisar el siguiente código y confirmarme que sea correcto, según lo que quiero hacer:

```
 if (window.innerWidth > 480 && window.innerWidth < 800 && window.orientation == 0
  ||
  window.innerWidth > 480 && window.innerWidth < 800 && window.orientation == 90) {

}
```

**¿Es correcto? O si tienen una forma mejor, por favor ayudenme poniendo el codigo. Gracias.**

Answer (score 2):

### Tema `resize`:

Lo que deberías hacer es agregar un *listener* al evento de `resize`. Esto lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
  // Ingresas tu código de validación aquí y ejecutas lo que corresponda
});
```

> **Para tener en cuenta:** Cada vez que ocurra un cambio de tamaños, ya sea por cambio de
>   orientación del dispositivo o porque se juega con el ancho de la
>   pantalla, este evento se disparara, tenlo presente.

### Tema `portrait` o `landscape`:

Para lo que es identificar si esta en `portrait` o `landscape`, mi recomendación es usar lo siguiente ya que es como si fuera css:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches) {
   // Es PORTRAIT 
}

if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches) {
   // Es LANDSCAPE
}
```

### Tema simular orientación y tamaños:

Por ultimo si quieres probar esto desde una computadora y rotar la pantalla, podes hacerlo con la consola de desarrollo de cualquier explorador. Por ejemplo con Chrome, apretas "F12" y luego "Ctr + Shift + M" y te abre la barra para seleccionar dispositivo, tamaño y orientación con la que quieras ver la pagina (como se ve en la imagen)

[image: toolbar para configurar el dispositivo]

---

¿Porque agregar un *listener* al `resize`?

Esto es porque el usuario puede cambiar la orientación o tamaño de su pantalla cuando esta utilizando el sitio y tu debes estar al tanto de este echo para realizar alguna acción, en tu caso ejecutar una animación.

**Ejemplo de uso del listener:**

```
function main() {
    // Donde esta el core de toda la logica

    funcion_validaciones() // Ejecutas para que se hagan las animaciones si corresponde.

    //Ahora agregas el listener para cambios futuros.
    window.addEventListener('resize', (event) => { // Asumo que puedes usar arrowFuntion en la version de js que usas
        funcion_validaciones()
    });

}

function funcion_animaciones() {
    // Todo tu codigo de animaciones
}

function funcion_validaciones() {
    // Todo tu codigo de validaciones
    // Que luego llama a funcion_animaciones() si corresponde
}
```

Comment: Resize parece una gran solucion, pero todavia veo un problema. Que solo funcionaria el script en caso alguien rotase su pantalla y de esta forma cambiase el ancho, pero a la gente que no rota no le funcionaria el script porque solo se dispararia en caso de "redimencion". Entonces supongo que debo hacer una combinacion de ambos, de mi condicional original + el tuyo con resize, pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo sin duplicar el codigo ¿me puedes dar una mano? O sea quiero tener esas dos condiciones en una misma para usar un mismo codigo de animacion

Comment: Lo que debes hacer es agregar, el listener al resize, pero no quitar tu ya actual codigo. Dentro del resize, llamas a la función que tiene el código de las animaciones, me explico? No debes copiar y pegar código, sino invocar la función.

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo con jquery...asi:

Comment: $( window ).resize(  function (  )  {  //ANIMACIONES  }  )

Comment: El problema es que como te dije, la animacion solo se va a ejecutar cuando cambie el tamaño de la ventana, y esto funcionara perfectamente para los que roten su pantalla con tablets, pero no funcionara para aquella gente que no rote, que simplemente cargue la pagina y baje a ver el contenido.. a esa gente no le funcionara porque no dispararan el evento RESIZE

Comment: Por eso dije que necesito usar el mismo codigo que tengo pero en un condicional que mezcle ambos, mi condicion inicial + tu condicion del resize...pero no se como hacerlo...O sea para que se ejecuten las animaciones al cargar la pagina, y en caso la redimencione

Comment: Veo que estas un poco desorientado con lo que digo, no hay problema, ahí subí un ejemplo medio burdo de como hacerlo, para ver si te orientas. Puedes definir las funciones de ejemplo de muchas formas, es solo una posibilidad, mas que nada para orientarte en el flujo

Comment: Creo que ya te entendi un poco, pero a mi manera, porque no estoy actualizado sobre eso de la flechita que hiciste. Te pongo un ejemplo simple y por favor me dices si es correcto: function lalo (  ) {

}

if ( window.innerWidth > 480 && window.innerWidth < 800 ) {
lalo()

window.resize( function (  )  { lalo() } )
}

Comment: dentro de la funcion lalo irian mis animaciones ¿es correcto?

Comment: Es correcto. La "flechita" te garantiza el contexto y otras cositas, es de ems6, es solo otra forma de declarar callbacks.

Comment: Muchas gracias señor por su tiempo, paciencia y ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que tengo entendido, la propiedad orientation ha sido considerada como obsoleta, aunque aulgunos navegadores puede que aún la soporten, eventualmente dejaran de hacerlo... 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientation

Por otra parte existe en modo experimental la propiedad Screen.orientation que esta soportada por la mayoria de los navegadores..

Checa Esto:

```js
var orientation = screen.msOrientation || (screen.orientation || screen.mozOrientation || {}).type;

if (orientation === "landscape-primary") {
  console.log("That looks good.");
} else if (orientation === "landscape-secondary") {
  console.log("Mmmh... the screen is upside down!");
} else if (orientation === "portrait-secondary" || orientation === "portrait-primary") {
  console.log("Mmmh... you should rotate your device to landscape");
} else if (orientation === undefined) {
 console.log("The orientation API isn't supported in this browser :("); 
}
```

Mas Información: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation

Además si estas usando un servidor local como xampp o wamp, puedes acceder desde un celular o tablet o cualquier otro equipo poniendo la ip local de tu laptop y luego la ruta a tu proyecto ej:

192.x.x.x/proyecto/index.php

Comment: No sabia que estaba obsoleto, gracias por el dato. Prefiero no usar el nuevo metodo si es que no es un estandar compatible con todos.